# Optimizer of a semi-discrete optimal transport problem

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Provided two probability distributions $\mu(dx)=\rho(x)dx$ and $\nu(dx)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\delta_{y_i}(dx)$ that are supported on some measurable set $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$, we consider the semi-discrete optimal transport problem defined by

$$\inf_{(X,Y)}~ \mathbb E\big[|Y-X|^2\big],\quad \quad \quad \quad (\ast)$$

where the inf is taken overall the pairs of random variables $(X,Y)$ such that $X\sim\mu$ and $Y\sim\nu$. Under **which conditions** on $\rho$, $(p_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ and $(y_i)_{1\le i\le n}$, it holds $\mathbb E[Y^*|X^*]=X^*$? Here $(X^*,Y^*)$ denotes the optimizer of $(\ast)$.

Any thoughts or references are highly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this impossible, since $Y$ is discrete and $X$ is continuous? Or should it be the other way around?

Comment: The optimizer may not be unique.